# Android responsive toolbar height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-orientation

As we know, the toolbar height should be different on portrait (56dp) and landscape (48dp). Is there a way to make the toolbar change its height (and scale the title and images too) on the orientation change?

I strongly wish to save this line in AndroidManifest, because it is very useful for other purposes:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

(It is useful to toolbar stay in searching menu. I don't actually know a nice way to do it without `android:configChanges`)

Answer (score 0):

There is an ugly way to do that as you know what will the height be , by using a  custom `TextView` as the title inside the `ToolBar` and later scale everything when user rotate the phone.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <TextView
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And here in your `Activity`'s `onConfigurationChanged`, we change the `ToolBar`'s height directly and set the text size of our custom title;

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    View tb = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView titleTextVIew = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        tb.getLayoutParams().height = (int) Tool.convertDpToPixel(48, this);
        titleTextVIew.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);
    }else {
        tb.getLayoutParams().height = (int) Tool.convertDpToPixel(56, this);
        titleTextVIew.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,20);
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```